# How to use `alias` attribute if symbol is defined in another file?

Tags: gcc, gnu

I am referring https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html to understand usage of `alias` attribute. It says, "It is an error if `__f` is not defined in the same translation unit."

I am using following code block in *startup.c* file in which `__interrupt_handler` is defined in another file (e.g. *xyz.c*).

**startup.c:**

`void Interrupt102_Handler    (void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias("__interrupt_handler")));`

**xyz.c:**

```
void __attribute__ ((interrupt)) __interrupt_handler()
{
  uint32_t interrupt_id;
}
```

What modification should I do to make it compile without any error?

Comment: I do not understand. `What modification should I do to make it compile without any error?` You should define `__interrupt_handler` in the same source file as `Interrupt102_Handler`, right?

Comment: That I want to avoid. Any alternate way similar to `extern` ?

Comment: But there is no way to avoid it. To use alias, you have to. Your alternatives is patching gcc to support alias attribute across translation units.